# if statement for a variable that varies slightly

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I didn't really how to write the title, but I have a an if statement and two variables `a` and `b`. I want it to check if the variable `a` is equal to `b` **or** if it varies by 0.1 (that means it can be higher or lower than a by 0.1). The way I tried is what is shown below:

```
a = 1
b = 0.9


if (a == b) or (a == b + 0.1) or (a == b - 0.1):
    print "it worked"
```

The problem is that this method seems overly long I want to know if their is a shorter method I can use to do this.

Comment: Do you mean the difference to be **exactly** 0.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to *vary*, you should **not check for equality**, but for **less than or equal**. Like:

```
if b-0.1 <= a <= b+0.1:
    # ...
    pass
```

or alternatively:

```
if -0.1 <= a-b <= 0.1:
    # ...
    pass
```

the latter will be a bit more efficient since the difference is only calculated once.

The first statement (`a == b`) is then unnecessary since it is implied by the above.

Furthermore note that is usually **not a good idea to check for equality with floating points** anyway: `0.1` cannot be represented exactly so `0.1` is something `0.0999....` or `0.1000...1`-ish. As a result the slightest the product of some formula can have a tiny difference and this will result in the check being `False`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `abs()` function

```
if abs(a-b) <= 0.1:
    pass
```